# Pytorch: Add information to images in image prediction

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, tensor, dataloader

I would like to add information to my current dataset. At the moment, I have six-frame sequences in folders. The DataLoader reads all 6 and uses the first 3 for predicting the last 1/2/3 (depending on how many I tell him to). This is the function for the DataLoader.

```
class TrainFeeder(Dataset):
    def init(self, data_set):
        super(TrainFeeder, self).init()
        self.input_data = data_set
        #print(torch.cuda.current_device())
        if torch.cuda.current_device() ==0:
            print('There are total %d sequences in trainset' % len(self.input_data))

    def getitem(self, index):
        path = self.input_data[index]
        imgs_path = sorted(glob.glob(path + '/*.png'))
        imgs = []
        for img_path in imgs_path:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (256,448))
            img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC) #has been 0.5 for official data, new is fx = 2.63 and fy = 2.84
            img_tensor = ToTensor()(img).float()
            imgs.append(img_tensor)
        imgs = torch.stack(imgs, dim=0)
        return imgs

    def len(self):
        return len(self.input_data)
```

Now I'd like to add one value to these images. It is a boolean, I have stored in a list in a .json in the same folder, like the six-frame-sequences. But I don't know how to add the values of the list in the .json to the tensor. Which dimension should I use? Will the system work at all, if I change the shape of the input?

Answer (score 0):

The function **getitem** can return anything, so you can return a tuple instead of just images :

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    path = ...
    # load your 6 images
    imgs = torch.stack( ... )
    # load your boolean metadata
    metadata = load_json_data( ... )
    # return them both
    return (imgs, metadata)
```

You will need to make `metadata` a tensor before returning it, otherwise I expect that pytorch will complain about not being able to collate (i.e stack) them to make batches

"Will the system work" is a question only you can answer, since you did not provide the code of your ML model. I would bet on : "no but it won't require significant changes to work". Most likely you currently have a loop like

```
for imgs in dataloader:
    # do some training 
    output = model(imgs)
    ...
```

And you will have to make it like

```
for imgs, metadata in dataloader:
     # do some training
     output = model(imgs)
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, it somehow looks like this. By this, I could load the metadata and do something with it, but not in the model, can I? Because the model only takes the imgs tensor. I would like to add the metadata to the input tensor for the model.
To be more concrete: I have images of plants. And the metadata is the information if the light comes from the left or right side in the next frame. I hope, the system could learn to interpret this additional information, to predict plant growth depending on the light

Comment: It depends, are you able to modify the code of the model, or did you download it directly from internet ? Because if you can, then you simply need to modify its `forward` function ; if not, then there's not much you can do, the model was just not designed to use this additional metadata, you may want to reimplement it yourself or find a different architecture on internet that fits your use-case better

Comment: Yes, It is my own model. But still. In the forward function: I can adjust it to accept more input, but then it is fed deeper into the system. At some point, I have to 'concatenate' the boolean with the image. Like transforming a tuple to a tensor. But this won't work because of the dimensions. 
Anyways, thank you. I will try to draw a rectangle on the bottom of the image, indicating the light and see what happens.

Comment: This means it's more a ML issue than a programming one. There are many different ways to incorporate a label in a model, with different use-cases and caveats. You need to figure out what's best for your purpose. Maybe read some papers about conditional CNN and see what is made in state of the art research. Once you know exactly what you want, you can ask for help here about implementing it :)